# Making a Mobile "Roadblock"

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

So I'm making this danmakufu game in Blender as a school project, and it's due by the end of May.

I have this little rocket:

[image: meet the player character, folks!]

And I have this... TIE fighter-like thing:

[image: this is the TIE in question, which is surprising because there is no "TIE" in "question"]

So I'm trying to make the TIE fighter's y-pos match with the player's y-pos, but not make it too fast otherwise the TIE fighter's just going to run into the storm of bullets produced by the player, but I also don't want him to go too fast (or else his bullets would be way out of synch.)
The problem is, however, is that it's decidedly NOT MIT AppInventor or Scratch. You can't just stick in a data block saying "glide to co-ords (objectx+100,objecty)" or "always repeat [wait 5 ticks] [create object "Doop" with (parentx,parenty) and (direction=playerhitbox)]" in Blender. How can such a function be attained in Blender?
Question 1 answered. onto the next one!
Also, how does one actually get the bullet to aim at the player, but not seek?

[image]

P.S. the person with the best answer gets to be mentioned in the credits!

Comment: Are you using python scripting, or just the built in controls for the game engine?

Comment: I really don't get the picture here ( maybe my poor english ) but uploading the .blend and adding more explanation could help ( me and others )

Comment: @Cyberchipz: Built in datablocks in game logic

Comment: @Chebhou: Okay, here you go

Comment: Edit: how do you do that?

Comment: Use a file hosting serve such as http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  That one is dedicated for usage on this site.

Comment: @X-27: too big a file. It's really big

Comment: sorry, got carried away with the whole starwars idea :P http://i.stack.imgur.com/yMlsZ.png

Comment: would it work for him to track to?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means

Comment: and yes, Radish of the Opera, that is indeed supposedly a TIE fighter.

Comment: @Nefer007 If you have a two big file again, contact me, I can add it to the service.

Comment: No, I actually got the first part down. It's been moved to another part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to keep the Tie moving in front of the player you can add some random motion on the Y axis with a constraint to keep it in the view, and to keep the Tie moving in front of the object on the X-axis you add some motion on the x axis:

[image]

to make a bullet be fired at a position without traking an object you can add another object that will track the hitBox and fire the bullets, when the box move the bullets will not track it

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was referring to the TIE fighter's bullets. They still home in on the hitbox.